# Find all polynomials $P(x,y)$ which satisfy $P(x,y) = P(x+1,y+1)$

Tags: polynomials

Find all polynomials $P(x,y)$ in two variable which satisfy

> $$P(x,y) = P(x+1,y+1)$$

I don't know how to solve Polynomial in two variables.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any _one-variable_ polynomial of $x-y$ would do.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I didn't get you! Would you please elaborate !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ be a solution. Fix $x,y\in{\mathbb R}$, and let
$f_{x,y}(t)=P(x+t,y+t)$. Then $f=f_{x,y}$ is a polynomial 
satisfying $f(t)=f(t+1)$ for any $t$. Then $f$ is constant on
$\mathbb Z$ by induction ; so the polynomial $f-f(0)$ is constant
on $\mathbb Z$, and is therefore identically zero. So, for any
$x,y,t$ we have

$$
P(x+t,y+t)=P(x,y) \tag{1}
$$

Taking $t=-x$, we deduce $P(x,y)=P(0,y-x)$. This concludes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

At any $(x_0,y_0)$, the directional derivative in the direction $\langle1,1\rangle$ is zero. So the polynomial must be constant along lines parallel to the line $y=x$. Such lines are characterized as $y-x=c$. So the value of the polynomial depends only on the value of $c$ and nothing more.

So $P(x,y)=f(c)=f(y-x)$ for some function $f$. $f$ too must be polynomial for various reasons, including considering partial derivatives.

So $P(x,y)=f(y-x)$ where $f$ is some one-variable polynomial.

Comment: It seems that that the directional derivative vanishes is not immediate. You need to use that $P$ is a polynomial somehow.

Comment: @JohnMa So I thought that would be clear. If a polynomial is constant on a 1D lattice like this, it's constant on the entire line. I was using the term "directional derivative" to avoid too much coordinates in the write-up, not to suggest taking a limit as something went to $0$.